# Understanding Scala Currying

Tags: scala, currying

I am following a course from coursera where this example appears in the lecture but when I try and run it, it throws an error as follows:

> missing argument list for method mapReduce in object HelloWorld
>
> Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
>   You can make this conversion explicit by writing `mapReduce _` or `mapReduce(_,_,_)(_,_)` instead of `mapReduce`.
>
> var doo = mapReduce(x => x,(x,y)=>x*y,0)

Below is the code that I want to execute.

```
def mapReduce(map: Int => Int, combine: (Int,Int)=>Int,
                zero: Int)(a: Int,b: Int): Int = {
  if (a>b) zero 
  else combine(map(a), mapReduce(map,combine,zero)(a+1,b))
}

var doo = mapReduce(x => x, (x,y)=>x*y, 0)
println(doo(1,4))
```

Answer (score 3):

`mapReduce` wants two argument lists, but your are giving it one.
Try this:

```
val doo = mapReduce(x => x, (x,y) => x*y, 0) _
```

or equivalently,

```
val doo = mapReduce(identity, _*_, 0) _
```

The `_` in the end stands for the second argument list. It tells the compiler that you want the suffixed value to be taken as a functional value rather than an expression to be evaluated.

You can also give compiler a hint to make the conversion happen automatically by explicitly declaring the expected type of the expession:

```
val doo: (Int, Int) => Int = mapReduce(identity, _*_, 0)
```

And don't use `vars`. They are evil. Just pretend, there is no such keyword in scala, until you learn enough of the language to be able to recognize the extremely rare cases when it is actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a undescore parameter in order to create a curried function. Like this:

```
scala> var doo = mapReduce(x => x, (x,y)=>x*y, 0) _
doo: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> println(doo(1,4))
0
```